# acts_as_follower with ajax does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm trying to use the acts_as_follower gem ([link)](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower) with ajax, as described [here](https://gist.github.com/tcocca/863091). The problem I have is, it follows/unfollows, but without ajax (you have to refresh the page in order to see the change on the button).

Here is my code:

user.rb, create.js.erb, destroy.js.erb, _follow_user.html.erb, show.html.erb are like on the second link, routes, users_controller and follows_controller are below:

users_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
    @description = Description.new
    @descriptions = Description.where(:user_id => @user.id).order("created_at desc")
    end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :users, :path => '', :only => [:show] do
resources :follows, :only => [:create, :destroy]
end
```

follows_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:user_id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
 end

 def destroy
   @user = User.find_by_username(params[:user_id])
   current_user.stop_following(@user)
 end
```

Comment: What's the view in which you're embedding the _follow_user.html.erb partial?  The create.js.erb and destroy.js.erb in that example assume the existence of a single #follow_user element on the page that wraps the _follow_user.html.erb partial.  Your example may be different or more complex (e.g. multiple follows per page).  Can you provide some more details on your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see anything initially off with this so a created a project to test.  If you've cut and pasted the code from the example, remove the `#jQuery` lines in the js.erb files, and you might load the page in a new tab or browser window.

After doing that it loaded up fine and the button changes as expected.  You can see the test project here:

https://github.com/trh/social_follow_ajax

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfectly after removng #jQuery! Accepted your answer.